# Sourceable script that doesn't "pollute" the environment?

Tags: bash, shell

Consider these 2 scripts:

envSetter.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

export ENV_VAR=6
return 3
```

sourceable.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

function main()
{
    local var=5
    source envSetter.sh
}

main "$@"

unset -f main
```

`envSetter.sh` is a script that sets some variables (and possibly performs other actions that affect the current shell (environment)). I need to create a sourceable script that will source `envSetter.sh` but will also clean up after itself. I.e. after running `source sourceable.sh` I want my shell to have `ENV_VAR` set but I don't want to have `main` (or anything else that `sourceable.sh` uses) defined.

The above scripts achieve that. However, on top of all that I want `sourceable.sh` to be able to return whatever exit code `main` returns. Right now the script returns the result of `unset -f main`. If I remove that command my script will leave `main` function defined which I don't want. If I try to use a temporary variable:

```
main "$@"
result=$?

unset -f main

return $result
```

It will return what I expect but will also leave `result` defined which I don't want. I could also not use a `main` function at all and put all the code in the top level of the script but that would expose even more garbage from inside `main` (e.g. `local var`) which I also don't want.

Is there a way to source `envSetter.sh` (i.e. let it set variables in the current shell), return whatever `main` returns and **not** "pollute" my current shell with anything `sourceable.sh` uses? To clarify: I **want** `envSetter.sh` to affect my current shell but **I don't want** `sourceable.sh` to.

Comment: Just a subshell? `( source envSetter.sh }`?

Comment: I thought about it too but if I use a subshell `envSetter.sh` won't be able to affect my current shell (e.g. set `ENV_VAR`).

Comment: Well, you said `not "pollute" my current shell`, then decide. You want to hand pick which variables you want?

Comment: Sorry if my intention wasn't clear enough. I did specify though: "not "pollute" my current shell with ANYTHING `sourceable.sh` USES".

Comment: The exit code of `source` is simply the exit code of the last command inside the sourced script. What is the purpose of the `main` function? If you just source your script, you have that exit code in `$?`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about hiding the `unset` command inside of the `main` function? Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

main() {
    unset -f main
    local var=5
    source envSetter.sh
}

main "$@"
```

Note that the return status will just propagate through, since `source envSetter.sh` is the last command in `main`, it'll become the return status of `main`, and similarly since `main` is the last command in the script, it'll become the return status of the script.

BTW, using a shebang on something that's meant to be run with `source` doesn't make much sense. I tend to use something like this:

```
#!/bin/echo Run this script with the source or . command.
```

Comment: `unset -f main` INSIDE `main` does the trick, thank you! Wouldn't even think something like that was allowed. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do your cleanup in a RETURN trap:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'unset -f main' RETURN

main()
{
    local var=5
    source envSetter.sh
}

main "$@"
```

Comment: The RETURN trap will remain after that, OP is going to have to reset it.

Comment: Then `trap - RETURN` inside the trap body?

Comment: @glennjackman That's a thought I had, and it seems to work if the script is sourced interactively. But it gives a syntax error when sourced from a shell script.  :(

Answer (score 0):

You can source the script in a subshell and output relevant stuff you want in a source-able form to stdout. Like so:

```
tmp=$(
   var=5
   # silence stdout so that it does not affect what we want
   source envSetter.sh >&2
   # modify the environment if you want to
   unexport ENV_VAR
   env_var="$ENV_VAR" # for example rename
   # output the environment in a format you want
   declare -p env_var ENV_VAR
   # declare -f function1 function2 # for functions
   # or printf "%q" "$ENV_VAR"
   # or write it to a file printf "%s" "$ENV_VAR" > somefile
   # ie. save the state where you want to
)
ret=$?
# Load hand picked variables.
eval "$tmp"
echo "ENV_VAR=$ENV_VAR ret=$ret"
```